# Tor country IP address problem!

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, help

I have a question about Tor browser. I set up exit nodes for US and I visits my new site 10 times per day from 10 different US based IP addresses but every day only 4 US based IP address visits counted and the rest is from other countries. Can you help me?
Following please find my setings:

```
ExitNodes {us}
DataDirectory C:\Users\florin\Deskto\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Tor
DirReqStatistics 0
GeoIPFile C:\Users\florin\Desktop\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Tor\geoip
GeoIPv6File C:\Users\florin\Desktop\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Tor\geoip6
```

Answer (score 0):

You should also set `StrictNodes 1` in your `torrc`. This advises Tor to only use US nodes. With this setting 10 out of 10 requests should come from the US.

However if you see a smaller number there might be some differences in the GeoIP databases. So if you're checking from which country Tor connects make sure to look into the `GeoIPFile` (set also in your `torrc`).